# Any idea what this pink whitish bump on my dog is?

Tags: dogs, skin-condition

[image]Saw this last month and vet said to observe probably just a fat cell but it grew an mm bigger this month also found one near my dog’s neck

Bringing my dog to the vet today to get checked again but you guys might have an idea? Or may have experienced this with your dogs?

Hope its not anything too serious

He’s a 2 year old Havanese-Bichon dog

Comment: where on your dogs body is this bump?

Comment: Near his hind and neck area. He got checked earlier today and vet said its too small so they cant tell right nowz they gave him a cream to be used for 2 weeks

Comment: Keep your eye on it and keep your vet alerted to any changes. Be sure to accurately measure it, like with a ruler you photograph beside the bump, and make sure the camera puts the date on the photo. That way you won't have any possibility of mis-remembering.

Comment: I have a 5 year old bichon mix as well and he has two of these on his back. The vet said not to worry but they’ve grown. What did yours end up being?

Answer (score 2):

My guess (I'm not a vet) is that it's a harmless skin tag. Some breeds are more likely to develop them than others and in general they're more visible on dogs with short hair. My former dog had numerous of them and the worst that ever happened was that he bumped into one while playing and it bled for a while.

If it is a skin tag, you can expect it to grow longer, but it shouldn't change color or cause any problems.

However, if this growth starts changing colors or gets a very irregular, bumpy surface or oozes any liquid, your vet should have a look again.

Comment: I was going to suggest "skin tag" as well. If I understand correctly, skin tags are related to diet (specifically sugar) and will go away when you remove or reduce treats that might include sugar (like the bits of cookie that I share with my dog).